# Import LWJGL.jar error

Tags: eclipse, class, scala

I'm getting a new error:

```
Starting up
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:68)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:84)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:101)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:128)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
at GameStarter$.main(SnakeGame.scala:43)
at GameStarter.main(SnakeGame.scala)
```

I have imported the `lwjgl.jar` libary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem with Scala. lwjgl consists of a part written in Java and another part that is native. The native part should be found in form of a `dll` (Windows) or `so` (*nix) file. You should put this path in the java.library.path property.

See the faq: http://lwjgl.org/faq.php#faq1